# Can't find windows defender in gpedit.msc

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I need to change some settings in Windows Defender but I can't find Defender in `gpedit.msc`.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no Windows Defender section in Windows Components section of gpedit.msc. There is a section named Windows Security for that. There you can modify settings related to windows defender. Also,  you will not find Windows defender in Settings app, it is named Windows Security.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Defender is now Microsoft defender. You can change the settings from there.
Under Windows components, search for Microsoft defender.